# How to insert a string of text after X paragraphs of an html fragment?

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

```
$content = "
<p>This is the first paragraph</p>
<p>This is the second paragraph</p>
<p>This is the third paragraph</p>";
```

Given a string of html content as above, I need to do an insert after the N'th paragraph tag.

How can I parse the content and do an insert of a given string of text, say 'hello world' after paragraph 2?

Comment: [Please don't use a regex to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#answer-1732454)!!

Comment: @JosephSilber: I would politely request that you stop posting that everywhere. It's [neither factually correct](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/345031) nor very [informative](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/73168/148103), and people obviously don't read past the off-topic joke.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are sure about the HTML structure of your string, you can count the seen paragraphs in the callback's static variable.

```
$content = preg_replace_callback('#(<p>.*?</p>)#', 'callback_func', $content);

function callback_func($matches)
{
  static $count = 0;
  $ret = $matches[1];
  if (++$count == 2)
    $ret .= "<p> Additional paragraph</p>";
  return $ret;
}
```

Note that this solution is not reentrant, it is only a concept.

Comment: +1 for a solution vs commentary :) Looks pretty simple. Checking it out now.

Comment: Would the answer be faster or slower then the explode|implode answer below?

Comment: Just with preg_replace (no need of callback):
`$content = preg_replace('#((?:\</p\s*\>[\s]|.*?){2})(\</p\s*\>)#im', '$1</p>additional text', $content, 1, $count);` will add additional text behind the third paragraph. Increase the number inside {} to skip more paragraphs; to skip n paragraphs set it to n-1; {1} will add text after paragraph two, as asked in the question.

Answer (score 7):

You could use PHP [explode](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp) and [implode](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_implode.asp) functions. Here's a concept:

```
$content = "
<p>This is the first paragraph</p>
<p>This is the second paragraph</p>
<p>This is the third paragraph</p>";

$content_table = explode("<p>", $content);
```

This will create `$content_table` with values:

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => This is the first paragraph
[2] => This is the second paragraph
[3] => This is the third paragraph
)
```

Now you can change whatever you want to, using `$content_table[2]` for paragraph 2. For example you can do:

```
$content_table[2] .= "hello world!";
```

When you're done, just implode the table to string again:

```
$content = implode($content_table, "<p>");
```

Comment: best idea/answer. save a lot of performance and works reliable! thanks

Comment: Very smart to use a simple explode function. Solved my problem perfectly and effortlessly.

Answer (score -3):

function can help str_replace()

http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php

```
<? str_replace('<p>This is the second paragraph</p>','<p>This is the second paragraph</p> hello world', $content);?>
```

Comment: @HoeHoeHoe, this code does what you ask, maybe I not understood

Comment: @del_dan What if second paragraph could be any other string? Seems like you assumed that it will always be _This is the second paragraph_, which (I think) wasn't RegEdit's intention.

Comment: truth is not the best solution. only one solution.